# What's this strange white rectangle behind my toolbar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-toolbar, material-components

[image]

I've been trying to get rid of it all day to no avail. Tried giving every view and layout around it an invisible background color. Also tried reducing the size of the layouts and views it's in. Those sharp white edges persist. What are they? Also hi this is text filler, website says there's too much code and too little text. "Hi text filler, you good?"

- **activity_main**.xml:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
  <include
      android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
      layout="@layout/toolbar"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainToolbar">

      <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
          android:id="@+id/tab_anim_appbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center|top"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
          android:background="#00FFFFFF">

          <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
              android:id="@+id/searchToolbar"
              style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center|top"
              android:background="#A106A1"
              android:elevation="2dp"
              app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
              app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
              app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

              <!-- dummy to catch focus -->
              <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="0px"
                  android:layout_height="0px"
                  android:focusable="true"
                  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

              <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                  android:id="@+id/searchView"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                  android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                  app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

          </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

      </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

      <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>

  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```
- The toolbar in code:

  ```
      //code to make the toolbar edges round
      MaterialToolbar searchToolbar = findViewById(R.id.searchToolbar);
      MaterialShapeDrawable searchbarBackground = (MaterialShapeDrawable) searchToolbar.getBackground();
      searchbarBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(
              searchbarBackground.getShapeAppearanceModel()
                      .toBuilder()
                      .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,100)
                      .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,100)
                      .build()
      );

      //code to add search function
      SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
      searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);//so that button on keyboard is a check
      searchView.setQueryHint("Search...");
      searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
              return false;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
              ItemAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
              return false;
          }
      });
  ```

Comment: If you are using latest Android Studio, there's a great tool included, named `Layout Inspector`, which you can use for debugging stuff like this. It shows all the layers and views inside your root view (it's been in there before, just not as sophisticated).
Here's more about it:
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Comment: You are using rounded corners on your Material Toolbar but the shadows are not rounded. Removing elevation should fix it

Comment: @PrimožIvančič Apparently the offender is either the AppBarLayout or the TooBar itself. I'm stumped.

Comment: @MervinHemaraju I tried removing `android:elevation="2dp"`. It made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the shadow of the `AppBarLayout`. Use:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

[image]